# Typescript mapping Json to interface parsing date

Tags: json, date, web, typescript

I'm mapping my JSON responses from the Server side code into an Interface, in this way;

```
objectFromJson: IMyObject = <IMyObject>jsonData;
```

The problem is, that the Json contains a Date, is there a way to automatic cast the date to an real Typescript Date without something like this:

```
new Date(parseInt(incident["CreatedOn"].substr(6)));
```

Answer (score 3):

> that the Json contains a Date, is there a way to automatic cast the date to an real Typescript Date without something like this

Your json seems to create date as a `number`. BAD IDEA. Reason:

- how about dates before 1970
- it is unreliable based on time zones

Prefer you return dates as strings. More API recommendations : https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design

If all you have is it returned as number than what you have is okay. Else if you have dates in a JavaScript recommended format e.g. `2012-01-01T12:00:00Z` you would do `var date = new Date('2012-01-01T12:00:00Z')`

Comment: yes you are right, but I wan't things like                                 var date = new Date('2012-01-01T12:00:00Z'),
I just want to put the JSON behind the Interface and get an correct Date object